# tabLayoutIndicator stick to top of tab

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I simply want my tab indicator in tabLayout stick to top (since my tabLayout sticks to bottom) but seems there is no obvious parameter for that:

[image]

I've tried:

- Setting scaleY to -1, which its useless since icon also gets reversed
- Using `app:tabIndicatorGravity="Top"` which seems doesn't exist and throws error:

```
Output:  D:\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_subact1.xml:59: error: attribute tabIndicatorGravity (aka assistant:tabIndicatorGravity) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

- Also setting background doesn't seem practical, so I need some help

TabLayout:

```
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/primary_dark"
                app:tabIndicatorGravity="Top">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:icon="@drawable/match" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:icon="@drawable/bet" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:icon="@drawable/team" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:icon="@drawable/cup" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post TabLayout XML?

Comment: @Datalux sure done

Comment: Have you tried via code using `setSelectedTabIndicatorGravity(INDICATOR_GRAVITY_TOP)` ?(https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout#setselectedtabindicatorgravity)

Comment: @Datalux sadly i only have setSelectedTabIndicatorColor and Height. Is it about my sdk version?

Comment: maybe you use an older com.android.support:design in your gradle. Try to use `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06`

Comment: @Datalux setting my target sdk and my compilations to 28 from 27.1.1 worked!post your answer please and i accept it including this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06`

Also setting target SDK and compilations to 28.